# Increment app badge on recieving ACS push while app on background: Titanium

Tags: push-notification, titanium, titanium-mobile, acs, badge

My application uses ACS Push Notification. I have implemented app badge in my application. But the problem is the appBadge doesn't incrementing automatically while receiving a push notification. I have used the following code in my app

```
var deviceToken;
Titanium.Network.registerForPushNotifications({
        types: [
            Titanium.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_BADGE,
            Titanium.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_ALERT,
            Titanium.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_SOUND
        ],
        success:function(e)
        {
            deviceToken = e.deviceToken;
            SubscribeToPush(channelName, deviceToken, type);
        },
        error:function(e)
        {
            alert("Error: "+ ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e.error)));
        },
        callback:function(e)
        {
            var badgeCount = Ti.UI.iPhone.getAppBadge();
            badgeCount = badgeCount + 1;
            Ti.UI.iPhone.setAppBadge(badgeCount);
        }
    });
```

I read [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/PushNotificationConfig) that ["callback function"](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/PushNotificationConfig-property-callback) invoked upon receiving a new push notification. So I set the following code as callback to increment the badge.

```
callback:function(e)
{
     var badgeCount = Ti.UI.iPhone.getAppBadge(); //Will return the app badges
     badgeCount = badgeCount + 1;                 //Incrementing the appbadge
     Ti.UI.iPhone.setAppBadge(badgeCount);        //Setting new appbadge
}
```

It works while the app is open and when it receives a notification, callback get fired and when the app go to background, the badge get appeared. But I want to increment the badge number when the app is in background or exited. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: I've added a request here: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TC-1937

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of research I have created a sample application to increment the appBadge while receiving a server push notification. **You can download  the code from [Increment the ios appBadge Titanium](https://github.com/tanand7/TiSampleApps/tree/master/IncrementAppBadge)**. Please follow the steps after downloading the resources folder.

> 1. Create a new mobile application project in Titanium.
> 2. Replace the resources folder with the one you downloaded.
> 3. Login to www.appcelerator.com, go to your app then go to Manage ACS
> 4. Create a new user as admin, set user as admin
> 5. Create a new Access Control List(ACS) using the admin user and give the ACL Name as **'SampleApp'**
> 6. Upload the p12 certificate for push notification
> 7. Now Install the application to your iPhone and run the app...

Each user of the app should have a custom object which stores the number of notifications. I'm updating them while sending a push and clears it while I resume/open the application. I tested it with my iPhone devices and it works perfect. However it takes some delays since I have to call ACS multiple times.

**UPDATE : Latest Titanium SDKs Support this feature by default.**

What you need to do is to change the payload as follows:

```
var payload = {"alert":"Hi, This is a test notification", badge: "+1"};
/*+1 will increment the current appbadge by 1, number of appbadge will be saved in the ACS*/
Cloud.PushNotifications.notify({
    channel: 'friend_request',
    payload: payload
}, function (e) {
    if (e.success) {
       alert('Success');
    } else {
        alert('Error:\n' +
        ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
    }
});
```

And this will increase the appbadge by one. And you need to reset the appbadge when you resume/open of your application as follows

```
Cloud.PushNotifications.resetBadge({
   device_token : myDeviceToken
}, function(e){
       if(e.success){
             Ti.UI.iPhone.setAppBadge(0);
       } else {
             //Error callback
       }
})
```